# Why does Jackson not parse a JSON serialized with the same ObjectMapper?

Tags: json, spring, kotlin, redis, jackson

I'm trying to serialize some big object with a lot of nested properties (a lot of them are polymorphic).
As for now, I got a problem when trying to serialize an object that is basically an empty placeholder:

```kt
class EmptyTagHolder<T> : TagHolder<T> {
    override fun contains(tag: T) = false

    override fun plus(other: TagHolder<T>) = other

    override fun plus(other: T) = TagSet(other)

    override fun iterator() = emptyList<T>().iterator()
}
```

And this is the `TagHolder`:

```kt
interface TagHolder<TagType> : Iterable<TagType> {
    operator fun contains(tag: TagType): Boolean
    operator fun plus(other: TagHolder<TagType>): TagHolder<TagType>
    operator fun plus(other: TagType): TagHolder<TagType>
}
```

There can be other implementations of `TagHolder`, one is actually mentioned here, the `TagSet`. But the point is, Jackson serializes instances of `EmptyTagHolder` like this:

```json
{
    "[package].EmptyTagHolder": [ ]
}
```

I need to store that big object I mentioned in Redis, it is basically an editor state that is expensive to extract from the actual database so it is stored in Redis as a cache.
And when it comes to deserializing of that object, Jackson fails on this `EmptyTagHolder`
thing with an error below:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `[package].EmptyTagHolder<[package].EntityTag>` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
```

So the question is: how do I make Jackson actually consume bytes it produced earlier?

**UPD**:
The class that contains this `TagHolder` properties:

```kt
interface Entity {
    val id: SourceAwareIdentifier

    val type: EntityType

    val tags: TagHolder<EntityTag>
    val adjacencyTags: TagHolder<EntityTag>

    val properties: PropertyStore
}
```

**UPD2**:
The actual class implementation:

```kt
data class LocalEntity(
    override val id: SourceAwareIdentifier,
    override val type: EntityType,
    override val tags: TagHolder<EntityTag>,
    override val adjacencyTags: TagHolder<EntityTag>,
    override val properties: EditablePropertyStore,
) : Entity
```

The json I get as the serialization result:

```json
{
  "entity": {
    "somepackage.data.network.local.model.entity.LocalEntity": {
      "label": "Test",
      "id": {
        "somepackage.data.network.model.id.impl.RawSourceAwareIdentifier": {
          "source": "local",
          "internalId": "local:57fc8745-706e-4159-847f-7a35182d330f"
        }
      },
      "type": {
        "somepackage.data.network.model.entity.EntityType": "Regular"
      },
      "tags": {
        "somepackage.data.generic.impl.TagSet": {
          "tags": {
            "java.util.Collections$SingletonSet": [
              {
                "somepackage.data.network.model.entity.EntityTag": "Lorem"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "adjacencyTags": {
        "somepackage.data.generic.impl.EmptyTagHolder": [ ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "somepackage.data.generic.propertystore.impl.BasicEditablePropertyStore": {
          "overlay": {
            "somepackage.data.generic.propertystore.impl.NoopEditablePropertyStoreOverlay": { }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should look into how to use the `JsonSubTypes` annotation

Comment: @Jorn how can it help me? It does recognize the type itself correctly when both serializing and parsing, it just fails to parse an empty array as `EmptyTagHolder` (not surptizing at all, but why did it serialize it as an empty array in the first place).

Comment: Neither `TagHolder` nor `EmptyTagHolder` has any serializable properties. What else did you expect it to do? I expect that Jackson has nothing to go on besides the value being an `Iterable`, and so it just writes an empty iterable. And since you haven't specified a specific subclass, it has no indication that you wanted an `EmptyTagHolder` on deserialization.

Comment: @Jorn it literally has a type annotation in the serialized JSON I presented. My ObjectMapper instance is configured to explicitly specify types for every value as `WRAPPER_OBJECT`. That `"[package].EmptyTagHolder"` property name is not something I defined. This was generated by Jackson as a type annotation.

Comment: Perhaps you can show the class that contains the `EmptyTagHolder`? I wouldn't expect that information to live in a property key.

Comment: @Jorn added to the question

Comment: That's an interface, not a class. So it doesn't explain much. I'm still curious how you got Jackson to generate that property key. By default, it will just use the field name.

Comment: @Jorn updated the question again. The class is just a data class implementing the interface so I don't think it'll give much more details though